# How to send a CTRL+C to a tmux pane using crontab?

Tags: cron, tmux

How can I send a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to my tmux tab using crontab? I have the following and it works for sending commands, but I'm not sure how to send a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to it.

```
0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/tmux send-keys -t 0 "CTRL+C"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Ctrl keys may be prefixed with `C-` or `^`

<sup>([source](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#KEY_BINDINGS))</sup>

```
0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/tmux send-keys -t 0 C-c
```

Comment: why my tmux just enter plain text "C-c" ?

Comment: @CSQGB I can only guess. (1) You used some similarly looking character instead of plain ASCII hyphen-minus `-`. (2) Or maybe tmux works fine and the program in the pane receives the character (or SIGINT) and *it* reacts by printing `C-c`. // If these guesses don't help then please ask a new question. Your question should contain more information (version of tmux, exact crontab line, program in the pane, …). Include a link to this answer if you think it provides context.